# Android inapp purchasing consume able product

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have implemented in-app purchased in my application and my product type is Managed and i am using API version 3.
When i make purchase from my credit card it is successfully done.
But the problem is if i uninstall my application and want to purchase this with same account it will charge me again?
According to Google rules of managed product type we only purchase the product once? But why is this happening ?
any one help me  please?
here is my PurchaseActivity.java class

```
public abstract class PurchaseActivity extends BlundellActivity implements OnIabSetupFinishedListener, OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener {

    private IabHelper billingHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_purchase);
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);

        billingHelper = new IabHelper(this, AppProperties.BASE_64_KEY);
        billingHelper.startSetup(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            Log.d("In-app Billing set up" + result);
            dealWithIabSetupSuccess();
        } else {
            Log.d("Problem setting up In-app Billing: " + result);
            dealWithIabSetupFailure();
        }
    }

    protected abstract void dealWithIabSetupSuccess();

    protected abstract void dealWithIabSetupFailure();

    protected void purchaseItem(String sku) {
        billingHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, sku, 123, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        billingHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


     */
    @Override
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase info) {
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            dealWithPurchaseFailed(result);
        } else if (pmg.SKU.equals(info.getSku())) {
            dealWithPurchaseSuccess(result, info);
        }
        finish();
    }

    protected void dealWithPurchaseFailed(IabResult result) {
        Log.d("Error purchasing: " + result);
    }

    protected void dealWithPurchaseSuccess(IabResult result, Purchase info) {
        Log.d("Item purchased: " + result);
        // DEBUG XXX
        // We consume the item straight away so we can test multiple purchases
        billingHelper.consumeAsync(info, null);
        // END DEBUG
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        disposeBillingHelper();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void disposeBillingHelper() {
        if (billingHelper != null) {
            billingHelper.dispose();
        }
        billingHelper = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working as intended - in your code you are *consuming* the in-app purchase immediately, which means you can then purchase it again:

```
protected void dealWithPurchaseSuccess(IabResult result, Purchase info) {
    Log.d("Item purchased: " + result);
    // DEBUG XXX
    // We consume the item straight away so we can test multiple purchases
    billingHelper.consumeAsync(info, null);
    // END DEBUG
}
```

There's nothing that says you can't purchase a managed product more than once. What you can't do is purchase a managed product *before a previous purchase of the same managed item has been consumed*. So this is working exactly as intended, and if you remove that call to `consumeAsync`, you'll see that you can't purchase it again.

#### Sample use case:

Imagine some game where you can purchase extra lives. First, the user would purchase the extra lives (a managed in app product), your game (client or server) would then add those lives to the user's profile, for example, and assuming that was successful, you'd tell Google Play that the purchase has been consumed.

This is important in order to handle error cases - for example say the user's device dies in between the initial purchase and the addition of lives to the user's profile. Your app can then, the next time it's launched, try again to add those lives, and consume the purchase on success. And, obviously you wouldn't want the user trying to purchase even more lives before you successfully grant them - which is why you can't purchase a managed product twice before it's been consumed.

Comment: Could you please tell me how can we check that user has already purchased our product?

Comment: Using the in-app billing API, you can query via getPurchases for any un-consumed products: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#getPurchases

Comment: So if my SKU id com.anything.pro.  then i pass that SKU in getPurchases ?

Comment: Thank you very much to solve my problem.
But i have another issue. can you please tell me how can i check that my user has already purchased the product when he reinstall my application from same google account ?
Thanks in advance